# How can i use DatabaseFacade ExecuteReader to execute a query .net 6?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to upgrade my .net core 2.1 project to .net 6
I used the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade  to raw the sql query.
in asp net core 2.1 that work correctly but in .net 6 i have this error:

Error   CS1739  The best overload for 'ExecuteReader' does not have a parameter named 'parameterValues'

My function is :

```
 public static RelationalDataReader ExecuteSqlQuery(this DatabaseFacade databaseFacade, string sql, params object[] parameters)
        {
            var concurrencyDetector = databaseFacade.GetService<IConcurrencyDetector>();

            using (concurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection())
            {
                var rawSqlCommand = databaseFacade
                    .GetService<IRawSqlCommandBuilder>()
                    .Build(sql, parameters);

                return rawSqlCommand
                    .RelationalCommand
                    .ExecuteReader(
                        databaseFacade.GetService<IRelationalConnection>(),
                        parameterValues: rawSqlCommand.ParameterValues);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post any errors as *text* in the question itself, not images. Images can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested

Comment: Are you using [this DatabaseFacade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade?view=efcore-7.0)? Why? That's an internal EF class. Applications don't need to use it. If you want to execute raw SQL either use eg `FromSqlRaw` or create a new ADO.NET connection and use it. If you want to generate SQL queries dynamically you can use one of the many SQL generators

Comment: You can use a library like [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to easily execute parameterized queries and map the results in a single line. You can use [SqlBuilder](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/tree/main/Dapper.SqlBuilder) to construct the query. Another option is [SqlKata](https://sqlkata.com/docs) which can create SQL queries, execute them and map the results

Comment: yes, i want user FromSqlRaw, But i want to have e method for any entity, i saw the example of FromSqlRaw but i must use it to a specific entity

Comment: in .net 6 there is not a specific overload  to doint it?

Comment: `FromSqlRaw` is a DbSet method so is available in all entities already. No matter what you do you *must* specify the target type. It's unclear what the question is - it's definitely not about DatabaseFacade

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve non-entity data? You don't need an ORM to do that, you can use ADO.NET directly. In any case EF Core 7 added the [SqlQuery method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types) to load and map non-entity data. You can already access the connection through the `Database` property. You can use that property with Dapper to pass parameters or map results.

Comment: EF Core isn't a data access library. It's an ORM that works on top of the data access library, ADO.NET. You don't need EF to query the database

Comment: this code is ugual con above in my question ? 
database.ExecuteSqlQuery(sql, parameters)
I think i can do it with this paces of code

Comment: You should never have used that class to begin with. It was never needed. You can fix the problem once and for all by removing the unnecessary code or you can keep trying to use **internal** classes that are free to change on every major version. EF Core 2 and 6 have huge differences.

Comment: If you insist on using that method why don't you check its parameters?

Comment: this issue is solved with the using SqlQuery method with efcore , 
thanks

Comment: The docs for ExecuteReader [are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.irelationalcommand.executereader?view=efcore-6.0). The signature is very different. Even in EF Core 2 you could use `var connection=myContext.Database.GetConnection();` to get the connection and then `var count=connection.Query<int>(someSQL);` to execute a query in just 2 lines